# tikz dashed edge does not shown up

Tags: tikz-pgf

Trying to draw a tree graph, I need some edges to be dashed, but the dashed line apear on the straight one wich make it not shown up (the node in the middle)
[image]

Here is the code I have tried

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (root){\includegraphics[scale=0.08]{img/hanging-over-the-key.eps}}
    child {node (a){\includegraphics[scale=0.08]{img/key.eps} }}
    child {node (b){\includegraphics[scale=0.08]{img/key.eps} }}
    child {node (c){\includegraphics[scale=0.08]{img/key.eps} }};
    \path (b) -- (c) node [midway] {$\cdots$};
    \path[->, dashed] (root) edge node {} (b);
    \path[->] (root) edge node {} (a);
    \path[->] (root) edge node {} (c);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: no, it does not, with \path it does apear above the straight line but with \draw it doesn't apear at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`edge from parents` is your frend:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=33mm, sibling distance=22mm]
\node (root){\includegraphics[width=11mm, height=11mm]{img/hanging-over-the-key.eps}}
child {node (a){\includegraphics[width=11mm, height=11mm]{img/key.eps} }}
child {node (b){\includegraphics[width=11mm, height=11mm]{img/key.eps} }
                 edge from parent[dashed,->]} % <----
child {node (c){\includegraphics[width=11mm, height=11mm]{img/key.eps} }};
\path (b) -- (c) node [midway] {$\cdots$};
\path[->] (root) edge node {} (a);
\path[->] (root) edge node {} (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

sorry, i haven't you image.